# How to plot a graph for the solution to a differential equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, series-expansion

I am very new to Mathematica and am struggling to get a plot for a differential equation I need solving.
I am doing a simplified version of the lane-emden equation for n=1 so have the follwoing equation to be solved
$$\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^2\frac{df(x)}{dx}\right)+f(x)=f''(x)+2\frac{f'(x)}{x}+f(x)$$
Since it has a singularity at zero, I have using the following approximation for near the origin:

```
series[x_] := 1 + x^2(-1/6) +x^4(1/120)
```

So my equation I want to be able to plot is the following:

```
sol = f[x] /. NDSolve[{f[x] + 2f'[x]/x +f''[x] == 0, f[0.1] == series[0.1], f'[0.1] == series[0.1]}, f, {x, 0.1, 4}]
```

When I do:

```
Plot[sol, {x, 0.1, 4}]
```

I just get an empty axis and no graph so I really don't know why it won't work or how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: 1) Use `:=` to define functions like `series` rather than `=`. 2) Your boundary conditions need to be expressed as equations, using `==` (`Equal`) and not `=` (`Set`). Make sure to run `ClearAll[f]` before your fixed code. 3) You can't have a non-numerical symbolic value like `x0` when you seek a numerical solution to your equation. If the solution is parametric, then use `ParametricNDSolve`; if `x0` has a value, then please include it in your definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Your simplified equation can be solved analytically:

```
sol =
 DSolve[
  {f''[x] + 2 f'[x]/x + f[x] == 0,
   f[1/10] == series[1/10],
   f'[1/10] == series[1/10]
  },
  f, x
]
```

[image: analytical solution with boundary conditions]

The use of your series expansion introduces the parameter `x0`. Since you don't provide values for it, I've chosen to show the results for $x_0=1,2,3$ below. Note also that the numerical values contain small  imaginary components that are due to numerical inaccuracies; you can get rid of those with `Chop`.

```
Plot[
 Evaluate@Chop[f[x] /. sol /. x0 -> {1, 2, 3}],
 {x, 0.1, 4}
]
```

[image: plot of solution for x0 = 1,2,3]

Comment: Using that DSolve function that you have, I am getting the error that 0 is not a valid variable?

Comment: You seem to be getting it but when I try and replicate it, it just isn't working for me?

Comment: @JordynTaylor The code shown to you works without any issues for me; `V13.0.0`. I had to grab the first definition of `series[x]` that contained a free parameter. Try to `Quit[]` or `ClearAll["Global`*"]` and the solution should be working fine!